# How to set different value for an item to an android spinner?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley, android-spinner

I have to set different value in an item to an Android spinner; when I click on an item of the spinner, that is represented as a string that show the name, I also have to take an other value for that item. I'm working on a project where I make a JsonObjectRequest and parse the json populate the spinner.

The code i use for the spinner is this:

```
MaterialSpinner spinner = (MaterialSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setItems("Ice Cream Sandwich", "Jelly Bean", "KitKat", "Lollipop", "Marshmallow");
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MaterialSpinner.OnItemSelectedListener<String>() {
    @Override public void onItemSelected(MaterialSpinner view, int position, long id, String item) {
        //Snackbar.make(view, "Clicked " + item, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(activity, item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Using this lib: https://github.com/jaredrummler/MaterialSpinner

So, how can I parse a json response and set 2 value for an item? (The string name that is show and an ID for that item, even in the json response.)

Comment: Please share your json response string

Comment: {
    "count": 2,
    "0": {
        "Information 1": {
            "name": "test 1",
            "testnumber": "22222",
        }
    },
    "1": {
        "Information 2": {
            "name": "test 2",
            "testnumber": "55555",
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a POJO class to store data parse from `JSON`

```
    public class AndroidVersion {
        String name;  
        String id;
    }
```

2. Prepared `List<AndroidVersion>` from JSON using Gson Library

```
    List<AndroidVersion> androidVersions = Gson().fromJson(json, AndroidVersion.class);
```

3. Create a custom  ArrayAdapter/ SpinnerAdapter with this List
4. Set this adapter to Spinner

Answer (score 0):

If you know the structure of the JSON, you can make POJO's representing the classes of the objects in the JSON, and then use GSON library to parse the JSON into your Java objects.

Use Gson() to parse your JSON list into a Java `List` and update the items in the `Spinner` with the new list.

Gson:

Gradle dependency:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
}
```

For samples and setting up Gson, the following are good links:
 https://github.com/google/gson - Official Site
 https://guides.codepath.com/android/leveraging-the-gson-library - Tutorial